# C# Run exe with bat file and set variable values through the bat file

Tags: c#, batch-file

I have a .Net Framework console app.
In the picture under you can see some variables. I want to set these with the use of a bat file.
I think it's possible but now sure how.

Has anyone done this before?

[image]
Example of how I have seen some similar types of bat files with inputs.
[image]

Comment: Don't post text as images!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the arguments from the `args` array that gets passed to the `Main` method in your code and use these instead of hardcoding the values of the variables:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string jsonPath = args != null && args.Length > 0 ? args[0] : @"C:\User\...";
    ...
}
```

You can then supply the command-line arguments in the `.bat` as usual:

```
my.exe arg1 args2
```

[Command-Line Arguments (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/command-line-arguments)